# pandas dataframe: how to select rows where one column-value is like 'values in a list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a requirement where I need to select rows from a dataframe where one column-value is ***like*** values in a list.
The requirement is for a large dataframe with millions of rows and need to search for rows where column-value is like values of a list of thousands of values.

Below is a sample data.

```
NAME,AGE
Amar,80
Rameshwar,60
Farzand,90
Naren,60
Sheikh,45
Ramesh,55
Narendra,85
Rakesh,86
Ram,85
Kajol,80
Naresh,86
Badri,85
Ramendra,80
```

My code is like below. But problem is that I'm using a for loop, hence with increased number of values in the list-of-values (variable names_like in my code) I need to search, the number of loop and concat operation increases and it makes the code runs very slow.
I can't use the isin() option as isin is for exact match and for me it is not an exact match, it a like condition for me.
**Looking for a better more performance efficient way of getting the required result.**

My Code:-

```
import pandas as pd

infile = "input.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(infile)
print(f"df=\n{df}")
names_like = ['Ram', 'Nar']
df_res = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for name in names_like:
    df1 = df[df['NAME'].str.contains(name, na=False)]
    df_res = pd.concat([df_res,df1], axis=0)

print(f"df_res=\n{df_res}")
```

My Output:-

```
df_res=
         NAME AGE
1   Rameshwar  60
5      Ramesh  55
8         Ram  85
12   Ramendra  80
3       Naren  60
6    Narendra  85
10     Naresh  86
```

Looking for a better more performance efficient way of getting the required result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass all names in joined list by `|` for regex `or`, loop is not necessary:

```
df_res = df[df['NAME'].str.contains('|'.join(names_like), na=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this hope you will find a great way.

`df_res = df[df['NAME'].str.contains('|'.join(names_like), na=False)]`